# How to add a bottom box shadow for table header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a bottom box shadow for the table headers, but for some reason, the shadow appears on the sides as well. The below is the code that I am trying with.

```css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers th {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0px grey;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I am looking for is a box shadow with `blur:2px`, `spread:0px`, `y-offset:1px` and `x-offset:0px`

Comment: means that you want the shadow to appear downward only

Comment: @Gad yes, just a bottom drop shadow,

Answer (score 2):

Guess this might be what you're looking for I make some edit on the `box-shadow` and I centered the table data `td` and table head `th` in order to make its appearance look nice

```css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  padding: 8px;
  /* added */
  text-align: center;
}

#customers th {
  /* edited */
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(128,128,128, .15);
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you edit and give blur value as 2px and spread as 0px, that is the issue which i have

Comment: I think I did it

Comment: Unfortunately no, just see the shadow is thick, without spread. You are setting the spread to 0px, which is why its becoming as thick and not what I am looking for.

Comment: you want me to decrease an opacity

Comment: try using `box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0px grey;` which is intended to have no x-offset, but it shows a line on the sides. I want this to just show just a bottom shadow

Comment: please check your solution, it has lines on the sides

Comment: not quite right, check the properties, the blur is 0px, https://ibb.co/gmh1Q6N

Answer (score 0):

You need to add negative value to the left box-shadow, so that it moves the shadow to the left side, making it all hidden behind the original element.

Edit: give shadow to the tr instead to remove the space in between shadows issue.

```css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  padding: 8px;
}

.headingtr {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px grey;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr class="headingtr">
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the shadow has a gap between each header items.

Answer (score 0):

You can add clip-path to clip the non needed shadow:

```css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers th {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0px grey;
  clip-path:inset(0 0 -10px 0); /* 10px or any bigger value than the blur */
}
```

```html
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```